# Stored Procedure of counting duplicate value with output variable in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by

I want to create stored procedure of counting duplicate value
here is code with out stored procedure

```
select count(PID) from tblPerson
group by Gender
```

tblPerson is my table and PID my primary key.
and this is my code for stored procedure and I need output so I have used it.

```
create proc  spcheckunique
@gender varchar(max),
@count int output
as
begin
    SELECT @count=COUNT(PID)
    from tblPerson group by @gender= Gender
end
```

and this throws me error 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spcheckunique, Line 547
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Help me to fix this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are almost there:

```
create proc  spcheckunique
@gender varchar(max),
@count int output
as
begin

SELECT @count=COUNT(PID)
from tblPerson 
where @gender = gender
group by Gender

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WHERE Condition instead of Group BY

```
create proc  spcheckunique
@gender varchar(max),
@count int output
as
begin
    SELECT @count=COUNT(PID)
    from tblPerson WHERE @gender= Gender
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
group by @gender= Gender
```

Remove the piece `@gender =`, you only need `GROUP BY Gender`.